# Hotkey for stabilize stroke

Tags: texture-painting, grease-pencil

How can I use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to control *Stabilize Stroke* when drawing in the texture paint mode, like with grease pencil.

[image: Draw in the Texture Paint window]

Comment: I believe 'Shift-S' toggles the Stabilize Stroke, at least in the keymap I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your keymap, you may need to set this to what you want but in the 2.7x keymap I use, the toggle is set here to Shift-S.
[image]